# Guardar el primer carácter de la salida de raw_input como valor decimal ASCII

Tags: python

Necesito hacer un código que convierta la primera letra de una palabra en un número.

He pensado que lo más fácil sería buscar su equivalencia en ASCII pero apenas tengo experiencia y ya me he roto la cabeza

Comment: Hola Pablo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Es siempre recomendable que agregues lo que has intentado para que tu pregunta sea bienvenida. Mírate [tour] y [ask] para conocer por encima el sitio y como realizar buenas preguntas. Te he contestado parte de tu duda ya que existe una función incluida en Python para obtener el valor decimal de un carácter ASCII, para aplicar esto a una cadena retornada por `raw_input` basta con que uses slicing y concatenación de cadenas. Intenta aplicar esta idea y si te atascas comparte el código parapoder ayudarte en base a él. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el valor decimal de un carácter usando el built-in `ord`:

> Given a string of length one, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character when the argument is a unicode object, or the value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string.

Tradución libre:

> Dada una cadena de longitud uno, devuelve un número entero que representa  el código Unicode cuando el argumento es un objeto Unicode, o el valor del byte cuando el argumento es una cadena de 8 bits.

```
>>> s = raw_input("Ingrese un carácter: ")
Ingrese un carácter: g
>>> ord(s)
103
```

se puede revertir con su función inversa, `chr`:

```
>>> chr(103)
'g'
```